# How to map parent=>children without navigation property on child

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Currently I'm trying to configure a parent => child relationship with codefirst db generation.

```
public class Parent
{
   public Guid Id{ get; protected set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; protected set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public string Name { get; protected set; }
}
```

This is how my entities are configured:

```
public class ParentConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Parent>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Parent> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Parent");
        builder.HasKey(parent => parent .Id);
        builder.HasMany(parent => parent.Children);

    }
}

public class ChildConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Child>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Child> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Child");
    }
}
```

It's only allowed to get children via it's parent. A child isn't allowed to know which parent he has.

However entiteframework core is adding a foreign key in the child table to the parent table. Instead I want to have a foreign key from the parent to the child table.

What am I missing?

Comment: How else do you think that the child collection can be maintained unless there is a link from the child table to the parent?

Comment: @Neil: My case is the following: in the ui I can select several options. These options are available in the database. When selecting those options they should be linked to the parent so I'll know which options where selected. However I don't want to know for each option where they are selected.. Maybe my design is wrong?

Comment: In a relational database the concept of "parent has children" is expressed as a foreign key in the child table. That's all there is to it. No matter how you're gonna use it in a UI. EF can map this relationship from Parent, from Child, or bidirectional, whichever suits you.

Comment: This looks like a xy-Problem. What do you want in your application? A parent with a ChildCollection? Then your design is right.

Comment: "*Maybe my design is wrong?*" Indeed. What you are describing is a many-to-many relationship with join entity (table) representing a selection.

Comment: @TomB. your described scenario could indeed be a many to many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Read more here: [Single Navigation Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#single-navigation-property-1)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
    .HasMany(p => p.Children)
    .WithOne();
```